# What could cause a UIImageView to only display / render half of the loaded Image?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, xamarin.ios, uiimage

When navigating through the app the header has a logo which depending on the section loads a header image. For testing I am always using the same image file for now, however... calling the same method to change the uiimageview's image (passing the uiimageview as a parameter) I sometimes get only half of the image being rendered... I thought at first it was perhaps the frame or bounds cutting it off, but setting clipstobounds, backgroundcolor to blue, and logging the frame / bounds shows that it's not that as far as I can tell. This is happening sporadically, so the same code will sometimes load the full image, sometimes only half.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
rightLogo.Image = null;
rightLogo.ClipsToBounds = false;
rightLogo.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
UIImage imageTest = UIImage.FromFile (path);
if (imageTest != null)
    imageView.Image = imageTest;
```

The frame/bounds of the imageview is always set to 90 from what logs tell me, the image has a height of 180 (for retina), the content mode is set to scale aspect fit...

To add to this:
I have found that setting it to not scale the image it will always display the full image. Wondering if it's an issue with scale aspect fit / full (tried both) causing this. I have tested on both an iPad 3 running ios7 and and iPad 2 running ios6 as well as simulator.

Comment: How is the image stored in the file system?

Comment: The image is downloaded on runtime (unless the file exists already) opening a file stream using `File.Open (filePath, FileMode.Create);`

Comment: Have you considered using a 3rd party library such as https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage? It has few built in options to handle interruptions when downloading the images.

Comment: The only thing is that once it's downloaded it won't open the stream anymore, however even using the same file it is sometimes sporadically only loading half of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Product in the xcode navigation bar and select Clean" or you can press UPkey + command + K.

Next delete the app from the simulator.

This should help it perform correctly.

Or

In the storyboard, select your UIImage and in "Size Inspector" go to content compression resistance and change to 100 on both horizontal and vertical.

Comment: Sorry, this happens both on simulator and on device, clean run on both. App loads up, it downloads the file, and updates the header. The image looks fine, navigate to screen 2 and it only shows half, go to screen 3, looks fine, go back to screen 2 and it's fine. As you move through screens sometimes it'll be fine, sometimes it will not.

Comment: @user3661140
What device are you using? 

Can you edit your post and show your method or a little more code to go by please? What segue are you using and are you using a prepareForSegue method?

Comment: Please check my edited suggestion regarding compression setting

Comment: Sorry, had gone home for the evening. Although I wasn't using auto layout, my autosizing was set to allow it to stretch in height. Removing this seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @user3661140
Glad I could help :-)